Cant get 2nd page of scanned Image in duplex scan operation with WIA 2.0 DLL (DUPLEX OPERATION)
Printers and scanners are used in a currently running automation. They made a new decision and bought S2060w model KODAK machines. Previously we were scanning and processing jpeg documents with the default settings, but with this new model I need to make different settings to scan. When I want to communicate to the printer with the default WIA dll and print, it throws an error by setting Page to 0 in an absurd way.
I solved this with the following code.
SetWIAProperty(device.Properties, “3096”, 1); // PAGES


static void SetWIAProperty(IProperties properties, object propertyName, object propertyValue)
{
    if (properties.Exists(propertyName))
    {
        IProperty property = properties.get_Item(ref propertyName);
        if (property != null && !property.IsReadOnly && property.get_Value() != propertyValue)
            property.set_Value(ref propertyValue);
    }
}

Afterwards this problem went away. The printer does duplex scanning at the same time. So when 1 page flows, it scans both sides in the feeder. I tested with IrfanView program to see if it can do this and yes it scans 2 sides at once. However, when I wanted to do this with WIA dll in my automation, I saw a lot of answers on stackoverflow and tried all of them.
I tried the following answer but without success:
WIA 2.0 Duplex property
The second time I did a show transfer or transfer when the first paper flowed away, I got a no paper WIA error code.
Although I set the DUPLEX setting to give the second page (which is sometimes 4 and sometimes 5 in the documentation), it could not work '4' in my scanner, I made it 5.
SetWIAProperty(device.Properties, “3088”, 0x005);
SetWIAProperty(device.Properties, “3088”, 5);

I tried both lines separately and failed again to take second page.
One cd instance:
CommonDialog cd = new();
scannedImage = (ImageFile)cd.ShowTransfer(scanner, formatId, false);
scannedImage2 = (ImageFile)cd.ShowTransfer(scanner, formatId, false); // EXCEPTOPN NO PAPER CODE 0x80210003

One instance two transfer:
scannedImage = (ImageFile)scanner.Transfer(formatId);
scannedImage2 = (ImageFile)scanner.Transfer(formatId); // EXCEPTION NO PAPER CODE 0x80210003

Two cd instance:
 ImageFile scannedFrontImage = ScanImage(scannerOptionsSurrogate, scanner);
 ImageFile scannedBackImage = ScanImage(scannerOptionsSurrogate, scanner); 

 private static ImageFile ScanImage(ScannerOptionsSurrogate scannerOptionsSurrogate, Item scanner)
 {
if (scannerOptionsSurrogate.ShowTransferDialog)
{
    CommonDialog cd = new();
    scannedImage = (ImageFile)cd.ShowTransfer(scanner, formatId, false);
}
}

How can I get the 2nd side without using any additional package or tool for our automation with WIA? Does anyone have any idea?
Thank you, good work.

According to here:  Setting WIA_IPS_PAGES (WIA_IPS_PAGES  3096 // 0xc18`) to 1 causes a scanner to process one side of the page...A value of ALL_PAGES (= 0) means that all pages that are currently loaded into the document feeder are to be scanned. .Also see: WiaDef.h.

@Itallmakescents Hey dude,
I did what you said and have problem about non-tiff show transfer throwing "Value does not fall within the expected range." exception then i changed it to TIFF format but cant access the second page again it throws "Value does not fall within the expected range." when i try to get second page. Do you have any idea about it? Thanks.
